# Postgresql enum broke during springboot 1.5->2.0 migration

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I am attempting to [migrate a project from springboot 1.5 to 2.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide).
So far all I have done is [rename some crud repo methods](https://spring.io/blog/2017/06/20/a-preview-on-spring-data-kay#improved-naming-for-crud-repository-methods) and update my gradle build file. Now when running my application I get this error when it tries to save to the DB:

```
| 2018-05-02 16:39:10.581 -DEBUG 20748 [Scheduler-1] org.hibernate.SQL              : insert into table_a (enum_column) values (?)
| 2018-05-02 16:39:10.581 -TRACE 20748 [Scheduler-1] org.hibernate.type.EnumType    : Binding [OPTIONA] to parameter: [1]
| 2018-05-02 16:39:10.620 - WARN 20748 [Scheduler-1] ne.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42804
| 2018-05-02 16:39:10.634 -ERROR 20748 [Scheduler-1] ne.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : ERROR: column "enum_column" is of type custom_enum but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 121
```

Everything was working prior to my attempt to migrate to the newer springboot version. I haven't seen anything in the migration guide that discusses this. Does anybody know of changes to one of these (or other common packages) that would cause this issue?

- spring-core-4.3.12 -> 5.0.5
- spring-data-jpa-1.11.8 -> 2.0.6
- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.5.8 -> 2.0.1
- flyway-core-4.2.0 -> 5.0.7
- postgresql-42.2.2
- hibernate-core-5.0.12 -> 5.2.16

Here are stripped down versions of the relevant enum code:

From my model, using JPA annotations

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_a")
public class CustomTable {
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "enum_column", nullable = false)
    private CustomEnum enumField;
```

Enum declaration

```
public enum CustomEnum {
    OPTIONA, OPTIONB
}
```

Flyway DB migration

```
CREATE TYPE custom_enum AS ENUM('OPTIONA', 'OPTIONB'); 
CREATE TABLE table_a (
    id                  bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    enum_column         custom_enum NOT NULL
);
```

Let me know if you need other package version numbers or additional code snippets. Thank you!

Comment: Could it have anything to do with https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#flyway ?

Comment: I believe I was running flyway-core-4.2.0 before I started so the step from version 3 was already complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further digging I realized that it wasn't just my enum type that was having issues, columns with jsonb type were having similar problems.
This got me looking into broader DB issues, and sure enough the following property from my application.properties was no longer working:

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.connection-properties = stringtype=unspecified
```

Which makes sense because I was using the default JDBC connection pool, which was changed from tomcat to hikari in SpringBoot 2.0.
To fix the issue all I did was replace the tomcat connection properties line  with:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties = stringtype=unspecified
```